# My while function that is in foreach isn't initializing? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Know this code is supposed find me a few positions that are within the given range and place my objects to those places. But it somehow fails to run a simple while function that will find those positions

```
     void SortCharacters()
{
    int i = 1;

    foreach (Transform child in Center.transform)
    {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        
        Debug.Log("**********************");

        while (x * x + y * y > 0.4f * 0.4f)
        {
            Debug.Log("-------------------");
            Debug.Log("a: " + x + " b:" + y);
            x = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 8) - 4) / 10;
            y = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 8) - 4) / 10;
        }

        float DistanceRoughly = (i / 6);
        float CalculatedDistanceMultiplier = (float)Math.Round(DistanceRoughly, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0) * CalculatedDistanceMultiplier;

        child.transform.position += pos;
        i++;


        Debug.Log("Found Obj: " + child + "   x:" + x + " y:" + y + " Mult:" + CalculatedDistanceMultiplier);
    }
}
```

so it prints out stars, childs and mult the way it should. But it is saying that my x, y both are 0 AND it does not print "-------------------".
P.S: it also does not print the "a: b:" thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your while loop you are checking:

`0 * 0 + 0 * 0 > 0.4f * 0.4f` which is not correct so it is not going inside of while loop. You set `float x = 0` and `float y = 0` so it is correctly following the code.

Comment: Don't hate yourself. Just upvote and mark it as an answer and continue :) These kind of mistakes can happen sometimes. Do not worry. Sometimes we can not see in front of us. Continue to work on your game and be creative, be happy!